# Could monero benefit from research done for bitcoin?

Tags: protocol

I'm interested if optimizations designed for bitcoin could work for monero, such as:

1. segregated witness / flexible transactions (http://zander.github.io/posts/Flexible_Transactions/) - is this even applicable to monero, or does it already have a neat transaction format?
2. xtreme thinblocks (https://bitco.in/forum/threads/buip010-passed-xtreme-thinblocks.774/) - is it even relevant, were there any studies done for monero block propagation times? Could it benefit from this kind of approach?

Comment: I don't think monero has transaction malleability, so SegWit wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I think mimble wimble would work for Monero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Research builds upon prior research, so yes, definitely. For example, RingCT builds on both Nicolas van Saberhagen's Cryptonote and Gregory Maxwell's Confidential Transactions for bitcoin, and merges them.

I hear some kind of SegWit is theoretically possible with Monero, though I do not know the specifics.

Block propagation is currently not very optimized I think. Transactions are sent twice.

Of course, every bit of research may not be applicable to Monero, but given both currencies are "standard" output based PoW curencies, there will be some overlap.

Answer (score 3):

It has already if I recall, stealth transactions were the result of research done for Bitcoin by Genjix. This has been the default address type used in Monero.