# What is transaction malleability, does Monero suffer this problem like Bitcoin?

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-size, malleability

does this effect monero in anyway and if it does would something like flexible transactions or segwit fix it? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monero has a simple transaction format and doesn't suffer from transaction malleability in the same way as Bitcoin does.

See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/is-transaction-malleability-an-issue-with-monero) and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/are-ringct-signatures-malleable) for more details on malleability, and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/756/could-monero-benefit-from-research-done-for-bitcoin) for flexible transactions / SW.